# Im Trying To Make A "Getting Everthing Ready" Kinda Thing

Tags: javascript

Step 1: I type `node .` in console

Step 2: The console says: "Im Getting Everything Ready Please Wait ..."

Step 3: After about 5s or so I want to get "Ready!"

So how do I do this? I don't want something like this in my console ...

```
Im Getting Everything Ready Please Wait ...
Ready!
```

I don't want that. I want to do something like this ...

```
Im Getting Everything Ready Please Wait ...
```

{ 5 seconds Later }

```
Ready!
```

I do not want to see "Ready!" after "Im Getting Everything Ready Please Wait ..." in my console. I just want "Ready!" in my console after 5 seconds or so.

Comment: You need to include the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `process.stdout.write` instead of `console.log` (since `console.log` adds a newline automatically), and then add a carriage return (but no newline) to your next write (and enough whitespace to overwrite whatever was on the line before):

```
process.stdout.write('Getting ready')
setTimeout(() => {
    process.stdout.write('\rReady!     ')
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Ok But This Is For A Discord Bot Though I Was Just Using Console.log As As Example